# Capturing Mouse Movements SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, mousemove

I'm trying to create a small draggable SVG rect in and HTML 5 page. What I'd like to do is get mouse capture when I click mouse down on the rect element. Unfortunately it seems that setCapture is not available on SVG elements. Is there another way to gain exclusive access to the Rect for mouse events in HTML5?

Answer (score 1):

You can use addeventlisteners . Below is the example of making svg element drag able:-
(i am using attribute to make sure its only svg element)

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown',mousedownfunction,false);

var Selectedelement=null;

function mousedownfunction(event){

  if(event.target.hasAttribute('isdraggable'){
     Selectedelement=event.target;
     document.addEventListener('mousemove',mousemovefunction,false);
     document.addEventListener('mouseup',mouseupfunction,false);    
   }

}

function mousemovefunction(event){
  // move your element here (logic of dragging)
}

function mouseupfunction(event){
document.removeEventListener('mousemove',mousemovefunction,false);
document.removeEventListener('mouseup',mouseupfunction,false);
}
```

Note:- i have'nt tested it, but it will work.  make sure you set attribute 'isdraggable' in rect i.e   `<rect x=0 y=0 width=100 height=100 isdraggable='true' />`